# Testing for null reference in F#

Tags: f#

Given the following:

```
[<DataContract>]
type TweetUser = {
    [<field:DataMember(Name="followers_count")>] Followers:int
    [<field:DataMember(Name="screen_name")>] Name:string
    [<field:DataMember(Name="id_str")>] Id:int
    [<field:DataMember(Name="location")>] Location:string}

[<DataContract>]
type Tweet = {
    [<field:DataMember(Name="id_str")>] Id:string
    [<field:DataMember(Name="text")>] Text:string
    [<field:DataMember(Name="retweeted")>] IsRetweeted:bool
    [<field:DataMember(Name="created_at")>] DateStr:string
    [<field:DataMember(Name="user", IsRequired=false)>] User:TweetUser
    [<field:DataMember(Name="sender", IsRequired=false)>] Sender:TweetUser
    [<field:DataMember(Name="source")>] Source:string}
```

Deserializing with `DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Tweet[]>)` will result in either the User or Sender field being null (at least that's what the debugger is telling me).

If I try to write the following:

```
    let name = if tweet.User <> null 
                  then tweet.User.Name
                  else tweet.Sender.Name
```

the compiler emits the error: "The type 'TweetUser' does not have 'null' as a proper value"

How do I test null values in this case?

Comment: Does `if tweet.User <> Unchecked.defaultof<_>` work? If not, then there's always the [`AllowNullLiteral` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353608.aspx).

Comment: Unchecked.defaultof<_> compiles but does not work at runtime (doesn't correctly match null). AllowNullLiteral is not valid for a record field. Good suggestions however.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To cyclically expand on @Tomas' answer ;-]

```
let name = if not <| obj.ReferenceEquals (tweet.User, null)
              then tweet.User.Name
              else tweet.Sender.Name
```

or

```
let inline isNull (x:^T when ^T : not struct) = obj.ReferenceEquals (x, null)
```

`Unchecked.defaultof<_>` is doing the right thing and producing nulls for your record types; the issue is that the default equality operator uses generic structural comparison, which expects you to always play by F#'s rules when using F# types. In any case, a null-check really only warrants referential comparison in the first place.

Comment: Makes sense once you understand the concept. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an advantage of using `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` here rather than just `null`?  Seems like the latter would avoid a function call, plus allow it to return the correct result for structs.

Comment: @DaxFohl : Instances of F# types are not allowed to be instantiated as `null` by default (see [`AllowNullLiteralAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353608.aspx)). The constraints used here specifically prohibit value types, as they make no sense here semantically. Lastly, `Unchecked.defaultof` is a compiler intrinsic (like `default` in C#) so there is no function call there.

Comment: @DaxFohl : As it belatedly turns out, my call to `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` was misleading as it always translated to `Unchecked.defaultof<obj>`, so `null` is appropriate here after all.

Answer (score 15):

To add some details to the comment by @ildjarn, you are getting the error message, because F# does not allow using `null` as a value of types that are declared in F#. The motivation for this is that F# tries to eliminate `null` values (and `NullReferenceException`) from pure F# programs.

However, if you're using types that are not defined in F#, you are still allowed to use `null` (e.g. when calling a function that takes `System.Random` as an argument, you can give it `null`). This is needed for interoperability, because you may need to pass `null` to a .NET library or accept it as a result.

In your example, `TweetUser` is a (record) type declared in F#, so the language does not allow treating `null` as a value of type `TweetUser`. However, you can still get `null` value through i.e. Reflection or from C# code, so F# provides an "unsafe" function that creates a `null` value of any type - including F# records, which should not normally have `null` value. This is the `Unchecked.defaultOf<_>` function and you can use it to implement a helper like this:

```
let inline isNull x = x = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
```

Alternatively, if you mark a type with the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute, then you're saying to the F# compiler that it should allow `null` as a value for that specific type, even if it is a type declared in F# (and it would not normally allow `null`).

Comment: AllowNullLiteral not allowed on record fields. Program faults accessing tweet.User when comparing to Unchecked.defaultof<>. In other words, just referencing tweet.User to do the comparison when it's null is enough to cause a fault. Weird.

Comment: @MikeWard The attribute needs to be applied to the type - in your case `TweetUser` - then it specifies that any occurrence of the type (not just in the field, but also in the `if` expression) can have `null` value.

Comment: I tried that also. AllowNullLiteral can't be applied to record types.  The reference.equals thing works as expected. Just one of those F# interop oddities we'll have to live with. Really like the langauge overall.

Comment: That proposed `isNull` function doesn't seem to work... If you invoke `Unchecked.defaultof<Foo> |> isNull`, the result is a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 3):

Though this question is old, I didn't see any examples of boxing to solve the problem. In cases where my presenter does not allow null literals, but may be set from a view, I prefer to use boxing.

```
isNull <| box obj
```

or

```
let isMyObjNull = isNull <| box obj
```

or

```
match box obj with
| null -> (* obj is null *)
| _ -> (* obj is not null *)
```