# F# implementation of interface method with type constraint

Tags: interface, f#, type-constraints

I have a stupid problem, I need to implement in F# class the interface which have following method:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    T MyMethod<T>() where T : class;
}
```

And I am struggling myself doing it in F#. I have tried different ways. But the problem is that an object of type T must be returned. Null is not accepted:

```
type public Implementation() = 
    interface IMyInterface with
        member this.MyMethod<'T when 'T : not struct>() = null
```

Error: *The member 'MyMethod<'T when 'T : not struct> : unit -> a' when a': not struct and 'a: null does not have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method. The required signature is 'MyMethod<'T when 'T : not struct> : unit -> 'T when 'T: not struct'*

So I have tried to put T as argument to the class, but still no I finished with error:

```
type public Implementation(data : 'T when 'T : not struct) = 
    interface IMyInterface with
        member this.MyMethod<'T when 'T : not struct>() = data
```

Error: *The member 'MyMethod<'T when 'T : not struct> : unit -> 'T when 'T : not struct' does not have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method.*

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of returning `null` (which is inferred to have some type `'a`, check by returning `null :?> 'T`) you can use

```
type public Implementation() = 
    interface IMyInterface with
        member __.MyMethod<'T when 'T : not struct>() = Unchecked.defaultof<'T>
```

I prefer `__` over `this` when it's not used.

**TL;DR;**

The `class` constraint in C# implicitly includes `null`. Unfortunately specifying that in F# is not allowed:

```
member __.MyMethod<'T when 'T : not struct and 'T : null>() = Unchecked.defaultof<'T>
```

results in:

> The member 'MyMethod<'T when 'T : not struct and 'T : null> : unit -> 'T when 'T : not struct and 'T : null' does not have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method. The required signature is 'MyMethod<'T when 'T : not struct> : unit -> 'T when 'T : not struct'.

But then, using classes and interfaces like these cross-language requires special attention anyways, because C# and the CLR allow `null` values whereas F# doesn't.

For comparison against `null` best overload F# `isNull` (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746618/testing-for-null-reference-in-f/10746877#10746877)):

```
let inline isNull (x:^T when ^T : not struct) = obj.ReferenceEquals (x, null)
```

unless your type allows `null` when you can use standard `isNull`:

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type Foo() =
    member __.Bar() = ()

(Implementation() :> IMyInterface).MyMethod<Foo>() |> isNull // true
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but depending on the context in which you need this class, it may not be what you want. If ``'T`` is a class, this implementation WILL return ``null``, and if it's an F# class, the compiler won't (easily) let you compare it to ``null``. So be on the lookout for that.

Comment: @OverlordZurg Thanks for pointing that out. I added a TL;DR; :-)

Comment: The code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10746877/636019) performs null checks for any reference type, F# or otherwise.